# Test the hypothesis that the rapists tend to receive sentences different from those of armed robbers.

Tags: hypothesis-testing, regression-analysis

It is known that armed robbers receive sentences normally distributed with a mean of 7 and
standard deviation of 7. A criminologist is interested in whether rapists tend to receive sentences
different from those of armed robbers. A sample of 10 rapists has a mean sentence of 5 years. Test the
hypothesis that the rapists tend to receive sentences different from those of armed robbers.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You should be aware that statistical hypothesis testing requires you to set a confidence level.  Also, $10$ is rather a small number for a sample.  Finally, it's odd that the standard deviation of the sentence for armed robberies should equal the mean.  Not impossible, but odd.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine exercises and which show no effort at all.  Please edit to include your efforts.   Failing that, I fear the question will soon be closed.